# Optional property on a component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a component that must have one of its properties be optional, like it either is there with a value, or its not there at all:

```
export default function Select({ListBoxProperty}) {

  return (ListBoxProperty ? <Component ListBox={ListBoxProperty} /> : <Component />)
}
```

If `ListBoxProperty` is undefined, the `ListBox` property should not be given to `Component` at all.

How can I do the above without the ternary operator, and do it within the properties of `Component`?

Comment: i think it must work correct did you got any error

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769387/selectively-rendering-optional-component-properties-in-react-jsx

Comment: if u don't give `ListBoxProperty` to `Component` because it's undefined, then inside `Component` because u did that `ListBoxProperty` will be undefined, so u didn't do anything different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selectively rendering optional component properties in React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769387/selectively-rendering-optional-component-properties-in-react-jsx)

Comment: My case works, but it is not good enough, JLRishe answered the question correctly , and you did not get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as "without the ternary operator" if it's outside of the line where you're creating `<Component>`, but here is a way that you can conditionally pass properties to a component:

```
export default function Select({ListBoxProperty}) {
    const propertiesToSend = {
        ...(ListBoxProperty ? { ListBox: ListBoxProperty } : null),
    };

    return <Component {...propertiesToSend} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
import React from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
  ListBox: unknown;
}

function Component(props: ComponentProps) {
  return <>foo</>;
}

export interface SelectProps {
  ListBoxProperty?: unknown;
}

function Select(props: SelectProps) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.ListBoxProperty &&
        <Component ListBox={props.ListBoxProperty} />
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

If it's necessary to return `null` then use ternary.